# Python SMTP library can't handle IPv6

Tags: python, sockets, debugging, smtp, ipv6

How can i add IPv6 option on SMTP library please ?

When i try to connect to SMTP using IPv6 i got this error :

```
 smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, source_address=('2a00:xxxx:5::1e7', 80, 0, 0))
```

Error : `TypeError: AF_INET address must be a pair (host, port)`

Which means smtplib.py doesn't support IPv6

I found an article about that "https://bugs.python.org/issue3461" . I tried to add the patch into my smtplib.py but it didn't work

Can anyone please help me to do this ?

Comment: You may need to surround the IPv6 address with brackets (`[` and `]`). That is required for certain things, such as in a URI.

Comment: I tried : source_address=('[2a00:xxxx:5::1e7]', 80, 0, 0))  and source_address=(['2a00:xxxx:5::1e7'], 80, 0, 0))   and also source_address=(['2a00:xxxx:5::1e7', 80, 0, 0]))

no one worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ... source_address=('2a00:xxxx:5::1e7', 80, ...
> ```

The error message is misleading. Doing an `strace` on Linux shows that it actually tries to bind to the given IP and port but fails - and then issues this misleading error message. Why it fails can have various reason, but typical cases might be that it is no permission to bid to the port (binding to port 80 as done here needs root privileges) or that the port is already in use by another socket (port 80 is usually used for web servers).

In general it is better to only specify the IP address and leave the port to 0. This way it will use the given IP address as source IP but pick a random (ephemeral) port as source port.

> I found an article about that "https://bugs.python.org/issue3461"

This is unrelated. It is only about the sender shown in the EHLO command during the SMTP dialog. If this is a problem just give the value to use with the `local_hostname` argument.

Comment: please i have a question concerning the port .

When i choose port 0 it works, but when i choose port 80 it didn't work, because port 80 already taken right ?  Same thing, if i have 3 smtp running on the same ipv6 '2a00:xxxx:5::1e7' , each script should have different port ? for example '2a00:xxxx:5::1e7',0,0,0  then '2a00:xxxx:5::1e7',1,0,0 then '2a00:xxxx:5::1e7',2,0,0 ?

Comment: As you told me, port = 0 will choose randomly. It worked on 1 smtp, but when i test 100 smtp for example, i got the same error : AF_INET address must be a pair (host, port)

Comment: @Addicted-Programming: Again, this error is misleading and hides the real error. It might be for example that you've run against the limit of open file descriptors. It might well happen if you don't specify a `source_address` at all, only that you then might get a more realistic error.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3's `socket.create_connection` obtains the first DNS resolution entry of the target address that is connectable (and this is a behaviour that is documented in Python as unstable by the DNS design).

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fdcb675e/Lib/socket.py#L824

The CPython implementation `_socket.connect` throws the error in question on seeing a mismatch between the socket's address family at create time and the address family at another time,

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aa6be0/Modules/socketmodule.c#L1807

Looking closer at `socket.create_connection`, I guess the `source_address` parameter cannot control the address family to use for the target.  The socket object `sock` is created in `create_connection` with the address family of the resolved target address.  Then `source_address` is used to specify the object's source with a call to `sock.bind(source_address)`.  It appears that at this point, if the resolved target was IPv4 but `source_address` was IPv6, the error is thrown?

As a possible fix that would not monkey-patch `socket.create_connection`, I can imagine that instead of providing a symbolic host name in the target address, the caller resolves the host name first to an `A` or an `AAAA` entry, depending on the desired family.  The caller supplies the numeric recod as the target address.  The source address's family should be in accord with the desired family, too.

In other words, the caller can use `socket.getaddrinfo` to find the required target address by the desired family.  Other callers such as users of the `request` library can hot-wire `socket.create_connection` with the same idea.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo